# Different style on chapter than table contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, chapters

I tried to style a chapter page using the `titlesec` and the `tikz` package like this one :
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fancy-chapter-headings/
But I saw that the table of contents and the bibliography page were styled the same way as the chapter.How can I use different styles in these 3 pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could move the definition with `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` inside the document body just after the lists and then recover the original style, or you could define two commands: one for the fancy headings and the other one for regular headings, so you can switch at will between styles:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}

\newcommand\fancychapter{%
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel##1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}
}
\newcommand\regularchapter{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge##1}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
}
\begin{document}

\regularchapter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\fancychapter
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\regularchapter
%Some additional chapter with the "regular" formatting

\end{document}
```

If you are using the `book` class, one could even hook into `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`, to apply the changes automatically for the main chapters and not for the ones in the `\frontamatter`, `\backmatter` parts; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}

\newcommand\fancychapter{%
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel##1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}
}
\newcommand\regularchapter{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge##1}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
}

\apptocmd{\mainmatter}{\fancychapter}{}{}
\apptocmd{\backmatter}{\regularchapter}{}{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\backmatter
\appendix
\chapter{Test Chapter}
%The bibliography could be here

\end{document}
```

Another option (suggested by **egreg**) is to use the `numberless` option for `\titleformat` and have two definitions, allowing to use one style for numbered chapters and another one for unnumbered ones (the initial lists, ToC, LoF, LoT, and the bibliography are usually build using `\chapter*`). In this case, one could say

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{20pt}{\Huge#1}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

%The bibliography could be here

\end{document}
```

Comment: The "extended" syntax might be useful: `\titleformat{name=\chapter}...` for fancy numbered chapters and `\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}` for `\chapter*`.

Comment: @egreg yes, you are right. I'll add that possibility to my answer (unless you want to provide an answer yourself).

Comment: Go forth. :-) I'll vote ASAP.

Comment: @egreg OK. Option added. Thanks :-)